# How to keep in sync the resources of two folders with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, tapestry, m2e

I use Eclipse + Maven and - for unit testing purposes -  the web framework I am working with  (Tapestry 5) requires that view elements (*.tml) that are in `src/main/resources` **also be present** in `src/test/resources`.

I am not sure how to make sure they are present simultaneously in both folders.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I am not familiar with Tapestry.  Guessing from the location, I assume these are resources (as opposed to source files).  Shouldn't the _test_ version of your resources be _different_ from the _production_ version?  I recognize that there could be overlap in _some_ resources.  I think in that cases repeating the same resource (or resource file) for test purposes is preferable to coming up with a clever hack.

Comment: @SriSankaran. Thanks. Both versions have to be strictly identical. My only problem is that the resources have to be in sync and I am not sure how to achieve this...

Comment: I concur with Sri Sankaran, but the crappy solution in a unix/linux environment would be to use symlinks. Of course that rules out Windows without cygwin.

Comment: @Antionio Actually, symlinks do exist in Windows. I think they were introduced with Windows 2000.

Comment: Really? Always learning something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource files don't have to be in both locations just so that Maven can find them. Instead, you can just tell Maven that you've also put some in the src/main/java folder. Put this snippet into the `build` section of your POM:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

For more information, take a look at the relevant sections in the [Maven Resources plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).